# Mono For android, Draw function

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, draw, polyline

I have a short, and maybe simple question for some of you, but:

How do I draw a polyline in android (like the way you normally do with `system.windows.shapes`)

I have searched around, but can only find how to make a single line. and not a line drawn by a collection of points.

thanks,

Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistake there is no function like Polyline, but you can do your own.

Just draw lines from point to point in cycle.

**EDIT**

Read this link [CrossGraphics](https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics), there you will find how to draw lines.

Comment: You mean like using a circular or Fifo buffer? and then draw all kinds of single lines?

Comment: Yep, and add  first element to end of that buffer for easy implementation (you can draw line from last point to first, but way adding first point at the end is prefered).

Comment: I will try do something like this tomorrow :)

Comment: I have looked into it, but i just don't get it started. For example, i cant even find the draw function in c# for android. And what is it with the protected overide void on draw? can you show me some examples to get me started?

Comment: You should download zip file with all css.

Comment: And don't forget to read https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics/blob/master/README.md